# R - power/exponential regression issue

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, power-law

I have the following data which I am trying to get a nice simple regression fit to it:

[image: data]

Looks simple enough, but using R's nls function and trying both a power (a*x^b+c) and an exponential (a*b^x) fits I get very poor fits (red line is the power regression result and green line is the exponential result):

[image: fits]

I've tried many possible  (changing starting parameters, different methods, etc.). Is there something I'm not seeing? I mean the data looks like a straightforward fit...

Any thoughts welcome!

Comment: Can you say anything about the nature of the variables? What are X & Y? This looks like a pretty small dataset; can you post it?

Comment: With few points and low noise, something will fit it. e.g. I got a good fit with a function of the form $y = c + a/(d - x)^b +\varepsilon$   (using starting points a=0.016,b=0.44,c=.05,d=1.01 and nls converged to the final estimates quickly from there). The question is whether that means anything at all (likely the fitted model is nonsense). Rather than throw random equations at it like that (until something sticks), it's better to ponder the nature of the variables / what kind of relationships make sense. Why does x seem to have an upper bound (d) and why does y seem to have a lower one (c)?